# Vue props not loading image or video sources

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I'm working on making components that allow me to define what content to display and providing a url to the assets, whether it's an image or a video, but when ever I define a prop with a valid asset that isn't default to the component, it dosn't load the video, or the image.

Parent component:

```
<PosterMedium
        Video__Background
        Video__Background__Source = "@/assets/videos/keyboard.mp4"
        Poster__Title = "Upgrade your workflow"
        Poster__Description = "Add to your productivity with our tools, build from the ground up on UIX with modern design trends in mind, all together to give you a powerful arsenal to boost your workflow. "
      />
```

Child Component

```
<template>
    <div class="poster" :key="Poster__Title">
        <div v-if="Photo__Background" :style="poster__image__background"></div>
        <div v-if="Video__Background" :style="poster__video__background">
            <video id="background__video" autoplay loop muted>
                <source :src="Video__Background__Source" type="video/mp4"/>
            </video>
        </div>
        <!--rest of code-->
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "PosterMedium",
    components: {

    },
    props: {
        Photo__Background__Source: {
            type: String,
            default: "@/assets/VRtualisLogoFontConverted.svg"
        },
        Video__Background__Source: {
            type: String,
            default: "@/assets/videos/keyboard.mp4"
        }
//...
    },
    data() {
        return {
            poster__image__background: {
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 0,
                right: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                left: 0,
                backgroundImage: 'url('+ this.Photo__Background__Source +')',
                backgroundSize: 'cover',
                backgroundPosition: 'center',
            }
//...
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The thing is, when ever I put in the sources as raw html, it works fine, but as soon as I try to pass it through props, it has an issue with loading the assets, and I've already tried using `:src="require(Video__Background__Source)"` but that just kills the component entirely.

The video is giving me the most issue, with just not wanting to load entirely when I opt to use the prop, but the image is fine with using the prop and it's default string, just the video source just not wanting to have anything to do with the prop, or it's default string.

Answer (score 1):

Just had to use `:Prop = "require('<source>')"` in the component props
Thanks again @MichalLevý

p.s
For the background image, I just opted for a normal image that is using the same fix.